# How to do a 3D carousel wth React

Tags: reactjs, carousel, slideshow, framer-motion

I cannot find how to do a 3D carousel (aka slideshow) with React being able to show at least three elements.
There seems not to be up-to-date libraries or components for that in npm :(

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting for a while, here is how I manage to do it using framer motion:

```
import './styles.css';
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [[activeIndex, direction], setActiveIndex] = useState([0, 0]);
  const items = ['', '', '', ''];
  
  // we want the scope to be always to be in the scope of the array so that the carousel is endless
  const indexInArrayScope =
    ((activeIndex % items.length) + items.length) % items.length;
  
  // so that the carousel is endless, we need to repeat the items twice
  // then, we slice the the array so that we only have 3 items visible at the same time
  const visibleItems = [...items, ...items].slice(
    indexInArrayScope,
    indexInArrayScope + 3
  );
  const handleClick = newDirection => {
    setActiveIndex(prevIndex => [prevIndex[0] + newDirection, newDirection]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-wrapper">
      <div className="wrapper">
        {/*AnimatePresence is necessary to show the items after they are deleted because only max. 3 are shown*/}
        <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout" initial={false}>
          {visibleItems.map((item) => {
            // The layout prop makes the elements change its position as soon as a new one is added
            // The key tells framer-motion that the elements changed its position
            return (
              <motion.div
                className="card"
                key={item}
                layout
                custom={{
                  direction,
                  position: () => {
                    if (item === visibleItems[0]) {
                      return 'left';
                    } else if (item === visibleItems[1]) {
                      return 'center';
                    } else {
                      return 'right';
                    }
                  },
                }}
                variants={variants}
                initial="enter"
                animate="center"
                exit="exit"
                transition={{ duration: 1 }}
              >
                {item}
              </motion.div>
            );
          })}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
      <div className="buttons">
        <motion.button
          whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }}
          onClick={() => handleClick(-1)}
        >
          ◀︎
        </motion.button>
        <motion.button whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }} onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
          ▶︎
        </motion.button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const variants = {
  enter: ({ direction }) => {
    return { scale: 0.2, x: direction < 1 ? 50 : -50, opacity: 0 };
  },
  center: ({ position }) => {
    return {
      scale: position() === 'center' ? 1 : 0.7,
      x: 0,
      zIndex: zIndex[position()],
      opacity: 1,
    };
  },
  exit: ({ direction }) => {
    return { scale: 0.2, x: direction < 1 ? -50 : 50, opacity: 0 };
  },
};

const zIndex = {
  left: 1,
  center: 2,
  right: 1,
};
```

Here is a code sandbox with the solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-3d-carousel-wth-framer-motion-rtn6vx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But there is no need to repeat the items, you can just check if there are not enough remaining and populate empty items with the ones from the beginning.

  `if (visibleItems.length < NO_OF_VISIBLE_ITEMS) {     
      const missingItems = NO_OF_VISIBLE_ITEMS - visibleItems.length;     
      visibleItems.push(...items.slice(0, missingItems));   
    }`