# React [component] Carousel 3d effect

Tags: reactjs, 3d, components, carousel, parallax

New learner here and trying to understand how to create image slider in React. For reference the slider is in WordPress as a plugin and it's implementationcan be seen live on the following website.

https://oncallservice.co.uk/

I cannot find an exact React library/component which has same effect as the one in reference link.

Exprer opinion is needed on whether if no such library/component exist for React and this must be created from scratch or as I'm new learner and not 100% familiar with resources available, then if someone with expertise can point in right library/component direction, please.

The closest I've come across or find is a link from here which is sort of same but not exactly same.

[How to do a 3D carousel wth React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267461/how-to-do-a-3d-carousel-wth-react)

The slider arrows are at bottom in this one. The flow of image slide is to the side horizontal.

I appreciate if you can help me with code or library and I can try to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to write java myself but I'm at night shift work and don't have code at hand to share.